# Saving unix timestamp in core-data converts it into a negative integere

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, unix-timestamp

I am trying to save unix timestamp to core data using the following code:

> ```
> NSManagedObject *managedPostObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDPost" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
> [managedPostObject setValue:[structureDictionary objectForKey:@"timestamp"] forKey:@"timestamp"];
> ```

The format that I am getting timestamp from remote server is as follows:

> "timestamp": 1323118064000

For some reason all the time stamp values gets saved as : -2147483648

I have tried INTEGER32, INTEGER64, Decimal, Double as well as string as the data type for timestamp but none worked.

**SOLVED:**
Following did the trick for me:

> NSString *timeStampStr = [[structureDictionary
>   objectForKey:@"timestamp"] stringValue]; [managedPostObject
>   setValue:timeStampStr forKey:@"timestamp"];

Comment: `NSDoubleAttributeType` will work, but make sure you don't create the problem in the processing of the value before you store it

Answer (score 0):

What if you make the field a string and then save this into it:

> NSString *saveValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
>   [[structureDictionary objectForKey:@"timestamp"] intValue]];

Comment: That did not work, but gave me the right direction, I eventually ended up doing this:     NSString *timeStampStr = [[structureDictionary objectForKey:@"timestamp"] stringValue];
    [managedPostObject setValue:timeStampStr forKey:@"timestamp"];

Comment: Saving it as a string and converting back and forth is fine for a small application but is not the "ideal" way of doing it. That being said, if it works it works!

Comment: @jshin47 what would be the ideal way?

Comment: I provided an answer below, but basically 1) make sure you assign the result as a `longLongValue` rather than `NSInteger` or `int`, 2) save the value in Core Data as `INT64` as you previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, to expand on Simon's comment, make sure you are not doing this to get your value initially:

`NSInteger timestamp = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"timestamp"] intValue]`.

It looks like a classic case of wrapping when the # is too big for the space.

Instead try something like `long long timestamp = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"timestamp"] longLongValue]`.

Then save it to an `INT64`.